# Can Neem Leaves be taken directly (Azadirachta indica, Nimtree)

Tags: dermatology, medications, natural-remedy

**[Nimtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azadirachta_indica)** is really precious when it comes to skin hygiene. It also has other vital health benefits.

**Is it alright to take the Nimtree leaves directly?** As I heard from a friend that it is harmful to take Neem leaves without any processing. Although it can be processed and the juice can be taken without any second thought.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would suggest doing extensive research into natural-remedies and be extremely cautious.

I understand that your original question was referring to the method, however I believe this information is relevant, as there are factors to take into account that suggest the method of direct ingestion may not be safe. Ultimately, you should contact a professional.

There is not enough scientific information to determine an appropriate range of doses for neem. Keep in mind that natural products are not always necessarily safe and dosages can be important. **Be sure to follow relevant directions on product labels and consult your pharmacist or physician or other healthcare professional before using.**

WebMD, not always accurate, does specify that Neem is taken orally, though it doesn't indicate what form (powder, leaf, pill, etc.). It has the following warnings and precautions about Neem in general:

> #### Overview
>
> Neem is POSSIBLY SAFE for most adults when taken by
>   mouth for up to 10 weeks, when applied inside the mouth for up to 6
>   weeks, or when applied to the skin for up to 2 weeks. **When neem is
>   taken in large doses or for long periods of time, it is POSSIBLY
>   UNSAFE. It might harm the kidneys and liver.**
>
> #### Children
>
> **Taking neem seeds or oil by mouth is LIKELY UNSAFE for children.** **Serious side effects** in infants and small children can happen **within hours** after taking neem oil. These serious side effects include vomiting, diarrhea, drowsiness, blood disorders, seizures,
>   loss of consciousness, coma, brain disorders, and death.
>
> #### Pregnancy/Breast-Feeding
>
> Neem oil and neem bark are **LIKELY
>   UNSAFE** when taken by mouth during pregnancy. They **can cause a
>   miscarriage.**
>
> Not enough is known about the safety of need during breast-feeding.
>   Stay on the safe side and avoid use.
>
> #### Auto-immune diseases
>
> Multiple sclerosis (MS), lupus (systemic
>   lupus erythematosus, SLE), rheumatoid arthritis (RA), or other similar
>   conditions: Neem may cause the immune system to become more active,
>   possibly increasing the symptoms of auto-immune diseases. **If you
>   have one of these conditions, it’s best to avoid using neem.**
>
> #### Diabetes
>
> There is some evidence that neem can lower blood
>   sugar levels and might cause blood sugar to go too low. **If you have
>   diabetes and use neem, monitor your blood sugar carefully.** It might
>   be necessary to change the dose of your diabetes medication.
>
> #### Infertility
>
> There is some evidence that neem can harm sperm.
>   It might also reduce fertility in other ways. **If you are trying to
>   have children, avoid using neem.**
>
> #### Organ Transplant and Surgery
>
> There is a concern that neem
>   might decrease the effectiveness of medications that are used to
>   prevent organ rejection. **Do not use neem if you have had an organ
>   transplant.**
>
> Neem might also lower blood sugar levels as mentioned earlier. There
>   is a concern that it might interfere with blood sugar control during
>   and after surgery. **Stop using neem at least 2 weeks before a
>   scheduled surgery.**

It would be safer to avoid direct leaf intake for children, the pregnant, and those trying to have a baby as well as those who have recently had a transplant.

http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-supplements/ingredientmono-577-neem.aspx?activeingredientid=577&activeingredientname=neem

Comment: It's a shame this has answer so few upvotes. When I came looking for this StackExchange Health site, I was sincerely hoping for a community that puts emphasis on evidence-based healthcare and skincare as opposed to the countless other online sites and forums that advocate "natural", "alternative" medicines whose efficacy aren't scientifically proven and that can actually be harmful. The amount of upvotes this sourced, reasonable answer has, in contrast with the amount that the question has - which already seems to have made its mind up about the plant's efficacy - is telling.